Postgres SQL tsvector case sensitive search for full text search
Currently I am using tsvector function of postgresql for full text search. But by default all word are converted to lower case and matches and all query are performed using case insensitive match. But I want to perform case sensitive matches. I tried creating a new configuration using simple configuration but still it is case insensitive.
# Created Configuration using simple
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION case_sensitive (COPY = simple);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION case_sensitive
  ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart, word, hword, hword_part
  WITH simple;

When I performed vectorization it convert all to lower case
select to_tsvector('case_sensitive ', 'CASE Sensitive query')

Is there any way to use text vector with out changing the case of input text

I don't think there is a way to do that. But it is a strange requirement; all languages that use the Latin alphabet upper case the first word of a new sentence.

@LaurenzAlbe trying to perform case sensitive vector search. By default it is case insensitive.

Right. You cannot have that.

@LaurenzAlbe can we fine tune the default parser and attain this?.

@LaurenzAlbe I am trying to omit the dictionary, stop word removal and preserve the same case while converting to (tsvector)[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-debugging.html#TEXTSEARCH-CONFIGURATION-TESTING]. Not sure if it possible but trying to see, since it is one of the requirement for our matching criteria to match by case.  Similar thing in elasticsearch  

I know what you are trying to do, and I keep telling you you cannot have it. You'd have to write a new kind of full text search dictionary. You'd have to modify the PostgreSQL source code.

@LaurenzAlbe thanks, just wanted to confirm it.
